# long to xml, xsd.exe, custom classes

Tags: c#, linq, xsd.exe

I have 3 classes that map to my database. I need to insert an xml file into the database via these classes. The xml and classes are structured differently. Should I use xsd.exe to generate the classes of the xml and then map these generated classes to my database classes? Or should I use linq to xml to directly map the xml to the classes.

Answer (score 0):

My experiences with XSD were that if it works for what you are using it for, its a very convenient thing, and completely worth doing.

On the other hand though, Depending on how familiar you are with using linq, you will probably end up with a better overall solution if you write the conversion directly.

XSD can be very convenient but I'm not always a fan of how the results are spat out. Overall Personally I'd lean towards using linq.